# Typescript Object [object Array] has no method 'includes' with Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I got this error when I try to execute the following code, I am using Ionic3 framework:

> ERROR TypeError {stack: "TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'in… (http://192.168.0.25:8100/build/main.js:4116:76)", message: "Object [object Array] has no method 'includes'"}

[image]

```
// console.log(this.events) => [7704] 
// console.log(event.id_calenda) => 7653 
if (this.events.includes(event.id_calendar)) {
```

It happens in my device with Android 4.4.4, the other one with Android 7 works good, why?

Comment: Probably because the Browser on your old device only supports an older version of EcmaScript

Comment: Agreed, the older browsers don't support `.includes`. You'll need to use a polyfill for it to work on those older browsers.

Comment: check out [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it using `Array.prototype.indexOf()` instead of `Array.prototype.includes()`:

```
if (this.events.indexOf(event.id_calender) >= 0) {
```

[Array.prototype.indexOf() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[Array.prototype.includes() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: `indexOf` counts from 0, so will return 0 if the item is first in the array. `indexOf` returns -1 if the item is not in the array. So the code should be changed to:

`if (this.events.indexOf(event.id_calender) >= 0) {`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same error on Android 4.4.2, but
it's needed to use `>=` operator to replace `Array.prototype.includes()` method:

```
if (this.events.indexOf(event.id_calendar) >= 0) {
```